# Create system backup of 23.04 with dd anno 2023?

Tags: partitioning, backup

After an excellent two days of troubleshooting and reinstalling ubuntu a couple of times I am looking for a way to save me time the next time I break my ubuntu installation.

I can read a lot online, but I am really looking for confirmation if I have the right idea in mind.

I have one disk of 1TB, divided in the following partions

```
- swap       32GB
- /          30GB
- /boot      500MB
- /boot/efi  1GB
```

My idea/hope was, that I can focus on `/`. If my hardware would start to fail, I have all relevant data backed up in online things. So I am not worried about "loosing data". I am worried about the time I loose to reinstall / configure everything again. So in case of hardware failure, I will accept the price to pay: replace hardware, install everything. Never happened before for me, fingers crossed ;-).

So, I want to create backups of `/` on a regular basis, so that if I do something stupid (like `sudo apt install something` which causes to fail the boot), I can restore the last backup for `/` and be up and running again. That backup is preferably as small as possible.

I want to create (and restore if needed) these backups using `dd` from ubuntu live (running on thumb drive). The backup will be a disk image of the `/` partition only. I will not touch any other partition.

Is this possible? Will this approach work? I know I can simply try, but I just spend two days reinstalling ubuntu, kind of hoping to not have to do it again :)

Comment: Consider using timeshift, it's in the standard  repos and this is exactly what it's for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end was brave enough to just try it out.

First I created an ubuntu live disk where I formatted my USB drive with two partitions in gparted.

- 10GB for ubuntu live (FAT32)
- 54GB for storage (ext4)

Copied the iso file on the ubuntu live partition

`dd if=/home/[username]/Downloads/ubuntu.23.04.iso of=/media/ubuntu/[usb ubuntu live partition] status=progress`

Created a backup from ubuntu live:

`dd if=/dev/[myrootpartition] of=/media/ubuntu/[myusbdrive]/hdd.img status=progress`

Tested it by changing stuff in ubuntu, ran `sudo apt update && apt apt upgrade -y`, then booted back to ubuntu live and copied the earlier created backup back to my root partition

`dd if=/media/ubuntu/[myusbdrive]/hdd.img of=/dev/[myrootpartition] status=progress`

Works perfectly